# How to select a specific value from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get a specific value from a dictionary pulled from a url where a user inputs a item name and need to find the number of the item I am not sure how to write the command. I am new to python and dict.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json


class Test:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role("Admin","Moderator")
    async def it(self, ctx , *, name):
        test = await self.bot.pg_con.fetchval("SELECT name FROM item WHERE name = $1", name)
        if name != "None":
            user = await self.bot.pg_con.fetchval("SELECT item_id FROM item where LOWER(name)= $1 ", name)

            if user is not None:
                with open(r'.\\cogs\config.json','r') as json_file:
                    data = json.load(json_file)
                    key = data["key"]
                    url = "https://api.torn.com/torn/" f"{user}" "?selections=items&key=" f"{key}"
                    data = requests.get(url).text
                    dict = json.loads(data)
                    print(dict)
                    name1 = dict['items'][user]['name']
                    print(name1)
                    weapon = dict['items'][user]['type']
                    description = dict['items'][user]['description']
                    market = dict['items'][user]['market_value']
                    buy = dict['items'][user]['buy_price']
                    sell = dict['items'][user]['sell_price']

                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{name1}",description=f"{description}",colour=discord.Color.dark_blue())
                    embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name="Type", value="{}".format(weapon),inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Market Value",value=f"$""{}".format(market),inline=True)
                    embed.add_field(name="Torn Buy Price",value=f"$""{}".format(buy),inline=True)
                    embed.add_field(name="Torn Sell Price",value=f"$""{}".format(sell),inline=True)

                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send("BAN Laz! Ban Laz!")
                with open(r'.\\cogs\config.json', 'r') as json_file:
                    data = json.load(json_file)
                    key = data["key"]
                    url = "https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=items&key=" f"{key}"
                    data = requests.get(url).text
                    dict = json.loads(data)
```

The data input by the user is hammer and I need to select 1 from the information below.

```
{"items":{"1":{"name":"Hammer",
               "description":"A small, lightweight tool used in the building industry. Can also be used as a weapon.", 
               "type":"Melee", 
               "buy_price":75, "sell_price":50, "market_value":74,
               "circulation":1282843,
               "image":"https:\/\/www.torn.com\/images\/items\/1\/large.png"}
}}
```

I tried to get it to work but was unsuccessful. I get type error: str object is not callable. I probably somehow didn't do something right.

```
            with open(r'.\\cogs\config.json', 'r') as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                key = data["key"]
                url = "https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=items&key=" f"{key}"
                data = requests.get(url).text
                my_dict = json.loads(data)
                item_found = None
                for index, my_dict in data():
                    # index gets '1', item_dict gets the rest
                    if my_dict['name']: "removed = keyword" because it needed a colon. 
                        item_found = index
                        break
                return item_found
```

Comment: `dict['item']['1']` is what you're looking for if I understand correctly.

Comment: Please don't create variables named `dict`. This will shadow the built-in `dict()` function.

Comment: Yes dict['item']['1'] is what i am looking for.. in this example.  hammer item  was just one item printed from the site. . so I have no idea what the number will be. I need to find that number by the name input in to a command.. It could be hammer it could be baseball bat. Each command input could be different up to 1000 items with different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the keyword (Hammer), is a value under the key 'name', then you could iterate over the items.

```
item_found = None
for index, item_dict in data.items():
   # index gets '1', item_dict gets the rest
   if item_dict['name'] = keyword:
      item_found = index
      break
return item_found
```

You could also try list comprehensions:

```
item_list = [key for (key, value) in data.items() if value == keyword]
```

This returns a list of items.  In the normal case, the input data dictionary would have multiple items, and there could be more than one hammer.

Comment: tried this also.. but get str object is not callable. Name is the input from the user.    item_list = [key for (key,value) in data() if value == f"{name}"]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: It would help if you would not use "data" for two different things. `data = json.load(json_file)`  gives data as a dict.   `data = requests.get(url).text`  gives data as a string.   I was assuming that data was the data read from JSON file `{"items"... `.